# Insert HTML in DOM

Tags: javascript, createelement, createtextnode

I need to insert this code JS in my html :

```
   var1 = "texte1" + "\ntext2"
```

I used:

```
var newPara = document.createElement('h1');
var texte = document.createTextNode(var1);
newPara.appendChild(texte);
document.body.appendChild(newPara);
```

When I alter this code, there is no problem.
But I can't insert in HTML because var1 isn't TextNode.
(I would like find a solutions without Jquery).

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: If I'm following you correctly, you have an HTML string in `var1`? It's not always the safest but if you have the HTML as a string, simply use `newPara.innerHTML = var1`

Comment: It depends on what you want to do (which should go in the question). Try escaping the content of var1,  like `var1= 'var1 = "texte1" + "\\ntext2"';`

Comment: Shorter: `document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("h1")).innerHTML = var1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confused, so are you trying to insert just the text into the element you created? Or pure JavaScript code into the HTML? If just text, get the element by tag or id (id ideally, more direct way less room for error and element checking), then insert the text into the innerHTML

```
document.GetElementById("IDValue").innerHTML = textValue
```

UPDATE:
As one of your responses said, set the `innerHTML` property before appending the element if it does not exist.